# Java sealed interface permits generic type: gradle complains, eclipse does not

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, ecj, java-sealed-type

I have three types, `A`, `B`, and `C`, which are defined as follows:

```
public sealed interface A extends Comparable<A> permits B<?>, C { ...
    
public non-sealed interface B<T> extends A { ...
    
public record C(String s, int i) implements A { ...
```

Everything compiles and works fine in Eclipse. Now when I run a gradle build, I get an error `error: '{' expected` at the place of the opening bracket at `permits B<?>`. When I remove `<?>`, so that the type definition is as follows (raw type):

```
public sealed interface A extends Comparable<A> permits B, C { ...
```

...then gradle doesn't complain and the build is successful. Is this a gradle bug or is the type definition I am using not allowed?

Comment: Sounds like when you use Gradle, you are compiling it with an older Java version that does not support sealed classes and interfaces.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Java Language Specification §8.1.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.6) the items of the `permits` type list must be without their type parameters.

So, **`permits B<?>`** is incorrect and **has to be corrected to `permits B`**.

Please make sure that `permits B<?>` does not give a compile error and `permits B<?>` does give a `B is a raw type. References to generic type B<T> should be parameterized` warning instead, [has been reported to Eclipse JDT](https://github.com/eclipse-jdt/eclipse.jdt.core/issues).

Comment: Small addition: in fact, due to type erasure, it doesn't make sense to write `permits B<?>`, since you anyway can't permit B<X> but not B<Y> for example. Hence they logically forbid it in the spec to avoid confusion.

Comment: @QuentinC Yes, it doesn't make sense. It's a bug of Eclipse JDT 4.24 showing a raw type warning for `permits B` and not showing a compile error for `permits B<?>`.

Comment: Thank you, howlger and QuentinC! Your reasoning makes sense, however, I've read JLS §8.1.6 now and can't find an explicit statement that the `permits` type list must be without their type parameters, how do you infer this from §8.1.6?

Comment: @user7291698 The grammar is given as `ClassPermits: permits TypeName {, TypeName}` not as `ClassPermits: permits TypeName [TypeParameters] {, TypeName  [TypeParameters] }`.

Comment: There is an open bug for the issue here: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=574573